# Visual studio for mac. Edit and continue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-for-mac

Может кто-то знает как запустить edit and continue на mac os?
не работает нормально отладка, а постоянно перезагружать тоже не вариант

Comment: Вы имеете в виду hot reload? Или что?

Comment: Hot reload это другая функция, а есть edit and continue